# PHP remove existing array

Tags: php, arrays, class

How do I remove existing arrays (see code below)?, I know CodeIgniter is a good framework, but I want to understand how CI manages their $this->data method.

My code:

```
<?php
class simple {

   public $data;

   public function set($key, $value)
   {
      $this->data[$key] = $value;
   }
}

class testa extends simple {

   function yoop()
   {
      $this->set('name', 'excelent');
      echo '<pre>'.print_r($this->data, TRUE).'</pre>';
   }

   function noop()
   {
      $this->set('level', 'normal');
      $this->set('power', 'high');
      echo '<pre>'.print_r($this->data, TRUE).'</pre>';
   }
}

$testa = new testa;
$testa->yoop();
$testa->noop();

/* EOF */
```

Current Results :

```
Array
(
    [name] => excelent
)
Array
(
    [name] => excelent
    [level] => normal
    [power] => high
)
```

I want to remove the existing array, and the final result I want is:

```
Array
(
    [name] => excelent
)
Array
(
    [level] => normal
    [power] => high
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see what you're aiming for here. Why not simply:

```
class testa {
   public $data;

   function yoop()
   {
      $this->data = array('name' => 'excellent');
      echo '<pre>'.print_r($this->data, TRUE).'</pre>';
   }

   function noop()
   {
      $this->data = array(
          'level' => 'normal',
          'power' => 'high'
      );
      echo '<pre>'.print_r($this->data, TRUE).'</pre>';
   }
}
```

Comment: if I'm doing that, i believe that is not a framework, and waste time if you write 10000 lines of code...

Comment: "_i believe that is not a framework_" - I have no idea what you're trying to say. You sound like you're using framework as a buzzword.

Answer (score 0):

```
$testa = new testa;
$testa->yoop();

$testa1 = new testa;
$testa1->noop();
```

Comment: thanks, but i think if I creates new class, CPU memory will be exhausted, any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do that,

you are trying to access the same array, but expect different results?
if you really want to do that(dont know why), you could set the array again, or could use two instance

just

```
<?php
class simple {

   public $data;

   public function set($key, $value)
   {
      $this->data[$key] = $value;
   }

   public function reset(){
       this->data = array();
   }
}

class testa extends simple {

   function yoop()
   {
      $this->reset();
      $this->set('name', 'excelent');
      echo '<pre>'.print_r($this->data, TRUE).'</pre>';
   }

   function noop()
   {
      $this->reset();
      $this->set('level', 'normal');
      $this->set('power', 'high');
      echo '<pre>'.print_r($this->data, TRUE).'</pre>';
   }
}

$testa = new testa;
$testa->yoop();
$testa->noop();

/* EOF */
```

Comment: @oknoorap: This creates a new array each time - how is that any different to @Ashwini's answer which creates a new `class` each time? In both cases, the previous instance will be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create another function to your `testa` class:

```
function qoop(){
     unset($this->data['name']); // this function remove $data key by 'name'
     $this->set('level', 'normal');
     $this->set('power', 'high');
     echo '<pre>'.print_r($this->data, TRUE).'</pre>';
}
```

---

the result would be :

```
Array
(
    [name] => excelent
)
Array
(
    [level] => normal
    [power] => high
)
```

---

**raw code** :

```
<?php
class simple {

   public $data;

   public function set($key, $value)
   {
      $this->data[$key] = $value;
   }
}

class testa extends simple {

   function yoop()
   {
      $this->set('name', 'excelent');
      echo '<pre>'.print_r($this->data, TRUE).'</pre>';
   }

   function noop()
   {
      $this->set('level', 'normal');
      $this->set('power', 'high');
      echo '<pre>'.print_r($this->data, TRUE).'</pre>';
   }

   function qoop()
   {
      unset($this->data['name']); // this function remove $data key by 'name'
      $this->set('level', 'normal');
      $this->set('power', 'high');
      echo '<pre>'.print_r($this->data, TRUE).'</pre>';
   }

}

$testa = new testa;
$testa->yoop();
$testa->qoop();

/* EOF */
```